# Adding slug to req params url in express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, slug

I'm using [the 'slug' npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slug) to give-strings-dashes-for-url-cleanliness. The library works when I console.log() a string, and it's required properly into all of the relevant controllers.

However, I can't figure out how implement slug() properly to format my URLs. The problem I'm having is that a product name might be "Foo Bar Baz Quux", but I can't seem to find the right implementation for slug() without disrupting the connection between the app.js route and the findOne query via mongoose.

app.js

```
app.get('/market/:product_name', marketController.getProduct);
```

controller.js

```
exports.getProduct = function(req, res, next) {

  var product_name = req.params.product_name;
  // var slugProduct = slug(product_name);

  Product.findOne({'name': product_name}, function(err, product) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    return res.send(product.data);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could "slugify" a product by defining a `slug` property while setting up your "Product Schema". I can confirm it works if using `mongoose` with along `mongoose-slug-generator` plugin, see [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-slug-generator)... You could set it up as follows:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const slug = require('mongoose-slug-generator');

// * mongoose slug generator options
const options = {
  separator: '-',
  lang: 'en',
  truncate: 120
};

// * Init mongoose slug generator plugin
mongoose.plugin(slug, options);

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  slug: {
    type: String,
    slug: 'name', // genarating slug from multiple properties is allowed ['name', 'brand']
    unique: true
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  brand: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Apple'
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

```js
exports.getProduct = function(req, res, next) {

  const { product_name } = req.params;

  Product.findOne({ slug: product_name }, function(err, product) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    if (!product) {
     return res.status(404).json({
       message: 'Product data not found.'
     );
    }

    res.status(200).send(product);
  });
}

app.get('/market/:product_name', marketController.getProduct)

// request

const response = await axios.get('/api/market/my-awesome-product')

// response.data

{
 "_id": "60fh4d37ac1a1c6f58d6a5f4",
 "name": "My Awesome Product",
 "slug": "my-awesome-product",
 "price": 85.9,
 "brand": "Apple"
}
```